# JavaFX - Indeterminate progress bar not moving even with Task

Tags: java, javafx

I am doing a simple UI using JavaFX. I created an application that processes SQL queries and Excel files, then displays a progress bar window while it is being executed. I have read many other stackoverflow questions that recommend the use of taks. However, even when using a JavaFX task, my progress bar is displayed, but remains empty. Here is my code:

```
public class ProgressBarWindow extends VBox
{
public ProgressBarWindow(Stage stage)
{
    final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
    pb.setProgress(ProgressBar.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    Label label = new Label("Le fichier de classement est en cours de création.");

    setStyle(
            "-fx-padding:10; -fx-background-color: honeydew; -fx-border-color: derive(honeydew, -30%); -fx-border-width: 3;");

    setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    setSpacing(25);

    getChildren().addAll(label);
    getChildren().addAll(pb);
}
}

// Called when the user clicks the Finish button in a wizard
public void finish()
{
    Task task = new Task<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public Void call()
        {
            try
            {
                StandingsCreationHelper.createStandingsFile();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Alert alertStandingsFileExecution = Dialog.getExceptionDialog(ex);
                alertStandingsFileExecution.showAndWait();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    new Thread(task).start();

    Scene scene = new Scene(new ProgressBarWindow(owner));
    owner.setScene(scene);
    owner.show();

    do
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // recommended because catching InterruptedException clears interrupt flag
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
    while (StandingsCreationHelper.isFinished() == false);

    owner.close();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Note: When running the ProgressBarWindow by itself (adding a stage and a scene and showing it manually), the progress bar displays the back and forth movement that I wish to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking the FX Application thread, preventing it from rendering. Never do this.

You should use the task's `onSucceeded` handler to execute code when the task completes, and the `onFailed` handler to manage exceptions. Both are executed on the FX Application Thread, which allows you to interact with the UI from them.

```
public void finish() {

    Task task = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            StandingsCreationHelper.createStandingsFile();
            return null;
        }
    };

    task.setOnFailed(e -> {
        Throwable ex = task.getException();
        Alert alertStandingsFileExecution = Dialog.getExceptionDialog(ex);
        alertStandingsFileExecution.showAndWait();
    });

    task.setOnSucceeded(e -> owner.close());

    Scene scene = new Scene(new ProgressBarWindow(owner));
    owner.setScene(scene);
    owner.show();

    new Thread(task).start();

}
```

Comment: Your code is much cleaner and it fixes my problem :)!  Just a detail, I had to add a cast exception in the setOnFailed command: Exception ex = (Exception) task.getException(); Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, yes, `getException()` returns a `Throwable`. Updated answer (you may still need a cast to pass it to your `getExceptionDialog(...)` method).

Comment: Still need the cast :). I was wondering, in my original post, how was I blocking the FX thread? I thought the task object was there to avoid that.

Comment: Because after you start the task you repeatedly execute `Thread.sleep(500)` on the FX Application Thread...

Comment: That is how I was making sure the window would not close on me lol. Thanks again for the help!